How to Create an AI Chatbot with Google GEMINI using Node.js?
I am currently working on a project where I need to create an AI chatbot using Google’s GEMINI. I have chosen Node.js as my development environment.
While I have some experience with Node.js, this is my first time working with Google GEMINI and I am not sure where to start. I have looked through the GEMINI documentation but I am still unclear about how to integrate it with Node.js to create a chatbot.
Could anyone provide a step-by-step guide or point me to some resources that could help me get started with creating a chatbot using Google GEMINI and Node.js? Any code snippets, tutorials, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Chat is also called multi-turn conversation, because the user and the ai take turns responding to messages.
There is an example already which shows how to store the chat history and hold on a conversation with the AI.
Build multi-turn conversations (chat)
const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");

// Access your API key as an environment variable (see "Set up your API key" above)
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.API_KEY);

async function run() {
  // For text-only input, use the gemini-pro model
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-pro"});

  const chat = model.startChat({
    history: [
      {
        role: "user",
        parts: [{ text: "Hello, I have 2 dogs in my house." }],
      },
      {
        role: "model",
        parts: [{ text: "Great to meet you. What would you like to know?" }],
      },
    ],
    generationConfig: {
      maxOutputTokens: 100,
    },
  });

  const msg = "How many paws are in my house?";

  const result = await chat.sendMessage(msg);
  const response = await result.response;
  const text = response.text();
  console.log(text);
}

run();


You just copy/pasted the code from another page. You cannot put that into an html file. Please elaborate.

Its node.js not client side javascript.
